# initialise variable from another variable type

Tags: java

I have the class which have the variable and method as below:

```
public class ProjectsPage extends State {
    private Container<Project> newcontainer;

    public ProjectsPage(Kick kick) {
        super(kick);
    }

    public void setItem() {
        newcontainer = ??? kick.proj
    }
}
```

Object kick has variable **proj** with the same type as newcontainer:

```
public class Kick {
    public Container<Project> proj = new ContainerDB();
    //here I add content to proj
}
```

Now I want to initialise newcontainer with the same constructor ContainerDB as **kick.proj**. In another words make an empty **kick.proj**. Something like this (since kick.proj and newcontainer uses the same interface):

```
newcontainer = new ContainerDB();
```

But the problem is class **kick** can change classes for **proj**.Like

```
public class Kick {
        public Container<Project> proj = new ContainerDBSQL();
        //here I add content to proj
    }
```

I need it (I mean initialise with the same type) since newcontainer later on should contain only specific entries from kick.proj. Not all entries.
How to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just initialize it in the constructor instead?

Comment: You want to set **newcontainer** to kick.proj or to set **newcontainer** to a new empty ContainerDB?

Comment: Your edit didn't answer either of the questions posted.

Comment: `but empty. How to do it?` What is empty?

Comment: Why dont you do like `public ProjectsPage(Kick kick) {
        super(kick);newcontainer = kick.proj;
    }`

Comment: Madhan, because kick.proj is full. newcontainer should only contain specific entries from kick.proj.

Answer (score 0):

try instantiating the object with this:

```
newContainer = kick.proj.getClass().newInstance();
```